# What is the proper way to test a highly concurrent worker thread system?

Tags: multithreading, testing, concurrency

I am working on a system that consists of:

1. A database
2. A bunch of threads pumping rows into this database
3. A bunch of threads working on these rows

The crucial point is that no more than one worker should ever be operating on a row at the same time.

Of course there are a bunch of strategies here...I can lock things at the database level, I can use mutexes, etc.

But regardless of how I implement this, I need to be able to test the system to make sure I've done it right.

What is the proper way to test this?

All I have been doing is running hundreds of threads and continually checking for accidental overlap.  The problem is, it's hit or miss. It's probability.  Even if I run 500 threads for an hour, there could still be a thread that overlaps another, only rarely.

Also, how do I even properly check for overlaps? The "overlap checker" itself has a finite resolution that might be missing the actual overlaps that are happening...

I know concurrency is a complicated topic but surely there must be some best practices or recommended ways of testing such a system, besides just running it for a long time and crossing ones fingers...

Comment: Do you workers thread (3) write back their results on the same table/row? Or do you have a results table? Single machine solution?

Comment: Yes, the same table/row.  And a single machine solution should be ok for now.

Answer (score 4):

You should just *rely* on the database, no need to cross the fingers: This is a core feature of any real database to support [transactions / ACID (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Do I'm missing something? What do you mean by 'threads could overlap' to work on the same row?

Comment: I've +'d this because I agree that at a low level this should be a feature the database manages for you. However, maybe there's some logic on top which can cause overlaps - e.g. if thread 1 reads, thread 2 reads, thread 1 writes, thread 2 writes - the DB might guarantee that the writes will be transactional, but the data being written may have come from inconsistent reads. In this case, see if you can adjust the architecture to allow you to rely on the DB's transactional guarantees for all operations... exact details totally depend on the application and DB being used!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to test this?

There's no easy answer here.  One thing to consider would be to create a database proxy that you can inject between your worker threads and your database layer that would catch overlaps.  You could record the row-id of the client operation in some concurrent map, removing it when the database RPC call finishes.

I'll use Java as pseudo-code.

```
 try {
     // add it to some atomic concurrent hash-map
     if (workingRowIdMap.putIfAbsent(rowId, null) != null) {
         // scream and shout and log a concurrency failure
     }
     // do the _real_ database stuff here
 } finally {
     workingRowIdMap.remove(rowId);
 }
```

It may be hard if you are dealing with SQL to extract the row-id of the data in question.  It may even be albeit impossible if the SQL you are dealing with is complex.  Hard to know without having more details about your schema.

Also, you are going to want your proxy to be as lightweight as possible otherwise you may hide problems if you add additional locks or too many memory barriers.

---

Another idea would be to use a database tool to look at the binary change logs to see if there is any overlap in instructions.  I know MySQL has some tools that allow you to investigate their binlogs.  Might be a lot of work to customize a tool to be able to determine if your data updates ever overlap however.

---

> Also, how do I even properly check for overlaps? The "overlap checker" itself has a finite resolution that might be missing the actual overlaps that are happening...

Agreed.  Testing for bugs is not an exact science -- especially with highly concurrent software.  The idea is to give it your best try.  I always try to simulate live service traffic which often is the best way to replicate the conditions that the software will see in production.  Replaying production logs may be able to help you detect issues.

Aside from testing, you might also be warranted to having some group code review sessions around the high concurrency portions of your software.  Properly isolating that code so that the locking is simple with good try / finally blocks, etc. would be a good investment as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do such a thing was to start a high amount of threads and then introduce random jitter by suspending and resuming threads randomly.

This gives you lots of interesting thread schedulings. It is a monte-carlo algorithm which gradually covers more and more of the search space.

Not that you can schedule threads randomly you need to assert that no errors are present. My best idea for your case: Add a new column `WorkerCount int not null`. Initialize it to zero. When a worker runs on it, increment it (don't set it to one - increment it). Put a check constraint there to check `WorkerCount IN (0, 1)`. When the worker is done, decrement the count.

This will break at the first overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your situation fully but following are something I am using to save thousands of records to database using multiple threads in C#

For saving multiple records concurrently to database without deadlock situation you can use SQLBulkCopy (ADO.Net) or bulk insert (SQL Server) utility.

They maintain the cocurrency and never lead to a dead lock situation.

For logging I've written a singleton class and passing its object to every thread , back in code I am using ConcurrentList and Lock(object) to store all the logs and after every 5 seconds I am  saving all those records to the database and cleaning the list, again using SQLBulkCopy command.

Let me know if you need more info...

Answer (score 0):

as you said in your question, the focus should be on testability, more than performance.

I suggest a producer/consumer model. You can have as many threads as you wish writing on the database (new rows) and let the database server handle the concurrency. This is the first part of the system, many threads pumping rows into a table.

To process only one time each row, I suggest a single thread responsible for loading new rows and pumping them on a Queue. Then, you can have as many threads as you wish to process the queue. When they finish processing, they can update the row on the database or write to an output queue, where another threads would collect and process update requests in batches.

Imagine you have a PROCESSING_STATUS column in your table and that new rows always have PROCESSING_STATUS = 0. So threads are free to add new rows to this table.
Another thread would continuously query (at predefined intervals/events or simply polling) this table, selecting all rows where PROCESSING_STATUS = 0. Then, each row would be added to the Queue. Once loaded, you can update the PROCESSING_STATUS to 1. You have to complete this before querying again, this is important to avoid loading the same row twice.

The real workers threads would consume this Queue, I'm supposing you are using a concurrent Queue or a similar structure, able to handle many consumers. The Queue algorithm should guarantee that only one thread can take the same element. This kind of Queue is easy to find in the standard libraries of Python, C# or Java. Then, the real tread would process this row and write them back to an output queue.

The thread responsible for writing back the rows would update the data the working thread produced and the PROCESSING_STATUS column, setting it to 2, for example. This update should be done using all known keys and values of the row, to be sure it was not changed since it was read. The writing thread should also check the value of affected rows on the update query, to check if the row wasn't deleted or changed since the processing.

Regarding the testability, you can check if there are unprocessed rows, inspecting their PROCESSING_STATUS column. If PROCESSING_STATUS=0 - this row wasn't loaded, if it equals to 1, it was loaded but not processed/written back. 2 means it was processed. You still have to check if the processing of each row was done correctly, but this is standard testing.

You can check if more than one thread tried to access the same row or if a row changed since it was first read checking the affected rows on the update statement. If no rows are being affected by the update, it means it was already processed or changed.

So, the key for testability in this scenario is to use Queues for thread synchronization and check your updates to the database. You can also use counters on the Queue and the processing threads to check if number of loaded rows = number of processed rows = number of written rows.

If you want many threads loading data from the database, you can extend the PROCESSING_STATUS column use too. Imagine unprocessed (new) rows will be added with PROCESSING_STATUS = 0. Then, a set of reading threads, each one with an unique number positive and different from 0 would combine an update with a limited select statement.
Something like:

```
update TABLE_X set PROCESSING_STATUS = MY_UNIQUE_THREAD_ID
where key in (select key from TABLE_X where PROCESSING_STATUS = 0 LIMIT 5)
      and PROCESSING_STATUS = 0
```

If the afected rows is not zero, this thread would have some rows to load. The next step would be to load all rows where PROCESSING_STATUS = MY_UNIQUE_THREAD_ID. Then, the same algorithm could be used again. When a row is processed, we update its PROCESSING_STATUS with the negative value of MY_UNIQUE_THREAD_ID. This way you use the database to handle concurrency for you, but this does not mean you will get the best performance. At least, the original problem would be solved: to process every row only once.

An alternative for loading a row only once without stressing the database server is to use a modulo operation on the key (if it is a serial key). With the modulo on the key (k % n_readers) on the select statement. To load:

```
SELECT * from TABLE_X WHERE (key % N) == MY_UNIQUE_THREAD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

To really test the overlap;

- Create a testset that is guaranteed to overlap (e.g. only input one identical row)
- Verify that your locking mechanism is working (e.g. log start and stop of work on every row)

To test performance you should create a testset that generates data in a productionlike way. And use comparable hardware and...

As for locking the row, if all is in one application I think I would create a ConcurrentDictionary with the IDs of the rows being worked on or something along those lines. Or use some system with ConcurrentQueues where rows are being processed by queuing/dequeing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract pieces of work and chain them by row_id, than you don't have to test it.

In .NET i would do something like like this:

```
private var rowWorkers = new Dictionary<int,Task>();

public void ScheduleWorkOnRow(int id) 
{
  // starting empty worker to be able to continue on it
  if(rowWorkers[id] == null) rowWorkers.Add(id, Task.Run(() => { });
  // scheduling continuation
  rowWorkers[id].ContinueWith(WorkOnRow, id);
}

private void WorkOnRow(Task task, object id)
{
  //your code
}
```

This snippet is far from ideal, but i think you can get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Like others before me have said, the only proper way is whatever works for you. There is no right or wrong, there is only good and better. With that being said:

Your goal is:

**The crucial point is that no more than one worker should ever be operating on a row at the same time.**

So you have thousands of threads on which only one thread can execute changes no matter how many of them are opened. Threads are created dynamically and its hard to keep track of them, only a waste of resources and time.

But the database is unique, and therefor instead of controlling the threads, we can bottleneck the database and only allow one thread per specific row. To do this we need to insert a new checker per column. Lets name the column **ThreadCheck** and it can be whatever you want, for this example lets put it text.

## 1 idea one - Thread Counter

The idea behind the column is that each thread that wants to operate on some row in the database is saved into the ThreadCheck as a Thread[Thread ID]. When the thread is done operating on the row, the ThreadCheck is saved as either a null or a specific value. It can be whatever you want, for this example lets name it "empty". So a thread finishes working and the value changes to empty.

## 2 idea two - Queue

The next thing to implement is a **queue**. The queue's logic is based on FIFO (first one in, first one out) and it can simulate a bank waiting list. In a bank we have multiple people try to service multiple clients. For your app though, this bank has only one person trying to service many number of clients (threads). As the queue is built, each new thread is given a waiting ticket, another simple counter simulating the place the thread is at the waiting list.

When a thread wants to operate on a row, and the row is empty and that thread has a waiting ticket the value of counter+1, it can operate on it. When the counter is 1, the waiting thread has a counter 2, and the next thread counter 3 until X.

Now to move the line forward you would need some sort of superior figure like a security guard or a manager that tells people "NEXT!!!". In the thread waiting list, this superior function could be a periodic loop, that moves the line forward ONLY WHEN the current thread finishes working. This saves both time and resources, making the loop event based rather than constant checking.

You can enhance the total queue with dynamic counter++ and counter-- and give waiting tickets a new value each time a thread finishes. Or apply a queue limit like 1234567890 threads active at one time. Any new thread is given a deny until the queue moves.

## 3 idea three - Summary

A thread is created and given a waiting ticket. When a thread finishes, the service counter moves the line one place up. All until the last thread. With a Thread Check and a Security Function pushing the queue, there is a bottleneck rather than a swarm of threads all wanting to operate simultaneously.

If there is a problem with the logic I tried to elaborate or you don't understand some part, comment me.

Also because you try to solve this by yourself, I haven't included any code on purpose to both help you devise your own and to save myself the trouble of trying to write something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than firing up a bunch of threads in the hope of triggering a Heisenbug, you might have a look at a tool like [Chess](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/microsoft-research-releases-testing-tool/212002025). I must admit I've never given it a spin, but it still looks like a fit for your problem, as it's meant to actively explore all interleavings that take place.

> According to the researchers, CHESS has been integrated into the test frameworks of many code bases inside Microsoft and is being used by testers on a daily basis.

Note that the project was originally developed as a win32 solution, but has been ported to [.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/CHESS/). The codeproject link from that page is dead, but a quick search reveals the code is [still available](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm splitting your question.  You seem to have conflated 2 things here.  1) How to avoid having multiple threads work on the same row? and 2) How to test your application to be sure that this is not happening?

One thing I don't see you mentioning is how to handle ordering of the threads who are making writes to the database.  When you're dealing with user supplied data, the order in which changes are applied can be extremely important. Just tossing this out there just in case.

**How to Avoid:**

You don't say which database you are using for this. Some of the higher end commercial ones have row locking and lots of other functions that might be of great interest to you.  You should talk to your DBA and see if they can't help you.  I completely agree that the proper place to constrain this is inside the database.  That's the only place you can really be sure to catch 100% of them.

That said, when you absolutely positively have to get it right, you should go for the multipart solution.  Then if one thing fails, the others just might be able to cover for it.  So add some of the other measures mentioned here.

**How to Test:**

Create datasets with known rows of overlapping data and then try something like Grimace's Chess tool.  But you need data that you KNOW will cause problems in order to see how the code is handling them and to see if it is handling them appropriately. Don't just keep tossing random data at it in the hopes that something will stick.  For example, what happens if you fire up 500 threads who are all trying to access the same row possibly because you've indicated the same primary key?